# Как сделать словарь с ячейками со значениями X и Y?

Tags: python, pygame

Как реализовать генерацию уровня (Местности) с ячейками 1000 на 1000, на python, в виде словаря где каждая ячейка будет содержать по два элемента, X и Y

X = 1 Y= 1, X = 1 Y = 2, ...... и тд.

По типу уровня в стандартной пошаговой стратегии.

Comment: Если поле сплошное, то в словаре пока нужды не видно. Может быть, подойдёт двумерный список? `field = [[0 for x in range(n+1)] for y in range(n+1)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написал функцию для создания массива из словарей.

```py
def generation(X:int,Y:int=None) -> list:
    return [{'X':x,'Y':y} for x in range(1,X+1) for y in range(1,(Y or X)+1)]

gen = generation(2) # Поле 2x2
print(gen) # [{'X': 1, 'Y': 1}, {'X': 1, 'Y': 2}, {'X': 2, 'Y': 1}, {'X': 2, 'Y': 2}]

gen = generation(1,2) # Поле 1x2
print(gen) # [{'X': 1, 'Y': 1}, {'X': 1, 'Y': 2}]
```

Comment: Спасибо  большое)

Comment: @Максим А как это будет использоваться?